# NHibernate - generated-by assigned guid is being overwritten on Save()

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Can anybody tell me why even though I have this mapping:

```
mapping.Id().GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

and I assign the id of my entity myself

after a call to

```
Session.Save(entity)
```

results in a new Guid different to the one I assigned on the entity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soo..having downloaded the NHibernate & Fluent NHibernate source and battled to get them to compile, and stepped through I stumbled upon:

```
s.Save(entity, entity.Id);
```

This forces it seems to use the supplied Id.

Now I am flummoxed and frustrated and dying to know why you need to do this for some assigned-id-entities and not for others...

**Hrummphh**

Turns out it was the difference between:

```
mapping.Id().GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

and

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

The former is accepted but ignored...

Answer (score 1):

I use assigned GUIDs often without problems. I think you should set a breakpoint on the setter for your Id property and check the call stack when it's being changed.